# how to fill NA with value in other rows in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, jupyter-notebook

I have a table like this :

```
 df =   pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'account_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'date':['01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019','01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019','01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019','01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019'],
                   'amount':[np.NAN,np.NAN,100, np.NAN,200,np.NAN, np.NAN,300,np.NAN, 400, np.NAN,np.NAN],
                   'transaction':[10,-20,30,10,-20,30,10,-20,30,10,-20,30]})
    print(df.head(5))
        customer_id account_id  date    amount  transaction
    0   1   1   01/01/2019  NaN 10
    1   1   1   01/02/2019  NaN -20
    2   1   1   01/03/2019  100.0   30
    3   1   2   01/01/2019  NaN 10
    4   1   2   01/02/2019  200.0   -20
```

The Amount is the sum total at the end of a given day, and the transaction is the daily transaction amount. 
The problem here is that not every account has balance or transaction. I need find a way to deal with accounts with only transaction

I want to `fillna` in `amount_x` using this logic:

For each financial_account_id if the `amount_x` is `NA`

then check if next row's value is `NA` or not.

For example, here for for `customer_id` `1` and `account_id` `1`, on `01/02/2019` the amount should be `01/03/2019's` `100-30=70`, and on `01/01/2019` the amount should be`01/02/2019's` `70-(-20)=90`
The ideal output should be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'account_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'date':['01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019','01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019','01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019','01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019'],
                   'amount':[90,70,100, 220,200,230, 320,300,330, 400, 380,410],
                   'transaction':[10,-20,30,10,-20,30,10,-20,30,10,-20,30]})
    print(df.head(5))
        customer_id account_id  date    amount  transaction
    0   1   1   01/01/2019  90  10
    1   1   1   01/02/2019  70  -20
    2   1   1   01/03/2019  100 30
    3   1   2   01/01/2019  220 10
    4   1   2   01/02/2019  200 -20
```

Comment: Please provide actual csv data, or a `df = pd.DataFrame({...` snippet with minimal data so people can a) see what you're doing, and b) copypasta in order to diagnose/troubleshoot your issue. Also, it's polite to say what you've already tried, and useful to demonstrate what a successful result would look like. (`result = pd.DataFrame...`, for example.) Thanks!

Comment: @Mike thank you for pointing out and i just edit the format. please have a look if you can help me with this! thank you

Comment: how do we know what the given amount is for any given day and for what account? the logic doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Datanovice the problem i have here is that not every account has amount or transaction, so there's some account with only transaction. I need to fill these account's amount. If my logic doesn't make sense, could you suggest what I should do to fill these NAs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know, if my solution will be helpful, because it is brute force one. However, have a look.

The main idea is to split dataframe to smaller ones, based on the combination of `customer_id` and `account_id`. After that you fill values in the smaller dataframes (by your algorithm being described above). In the end, you merge them as filled.

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make df, as you have written above
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'customer_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
     'account_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2],
     'date':['01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019','01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019',
             '01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019','01/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019'],
     'amount':[np.NAN,np.NAN,100, np.NAN,200,np.NAN, np.NAN,300,np.NAN, 400, np.NAN,np.NAN],
     'transaction':[10,-20,30,10,-20,30,10,-20,30,10,-20,30]})

# make a new identifier (combination of customer_id and acount_id)
def get_cid_aid_combination(row):
    cid = row['customer_id']
    aid = row['account_id']
    return f'{cid}-{aid}'

df['cid_aid'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_cid_aid_combination(row), axis=1)

# fill it up
list_with_dfs = []

for cid_aid in df.cid_aid.unique():
    df_part = df[df['cid_aid']==cid_aid]
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < len(df_part):
        for i, amount, trans in zip(df_part.index, df_part.amount, df_part.transaction):
            if pd.isnull(amount) and i+1 in df_part.index:
                if pd.notnull(df_part.loc[i+1, 'amount']):
                    df_part.loc[i, 'amount'] = df_part.loc[i+1, 'amount'] - df_part.loc[i+1, 'transaction']
            if pd.isnull(amount) and i-1 in df_part.index:
                if pd.notnull(df_part.loc[i-1, 'amount']):
                    df_part.loc[i, 'amount'] = df_part.loc[i-1, 'amount'] + df_part.loc[i, 'transaction']

        cnt += 1
    list_with_dfs.append(df_part)

# make a df with filled amount feature
df = pd.concat(list_with_dfs)
```

Comment: Hi Jaroslav, Thank you for the reply, I tried your answer but it seems that  some dates' values are still NA in the result. For exmaple, customer_id=1, account_id=2 and date=01/03/2019 which ideally should be 230 (yesterday's amount 200+this date's transaction 30). Could you suggest where should be improved?  The problem i have here is that not every account has amount or transaction, so there's some account with only transaction. I need to fill these account's amount could you suggest how can I fill these NAs if my logic doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: Hello @kylechan, I am sorry for misunderstanding. I think your logic makes sense, I just did not understand it fully. A moment ago, I have edited my answer. Now, I think it works as you wanted. Please, leave a comment, if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, your solution is great and helpful, I learnt a lot from your answer. Thank you so much

Comment: I am glad I could help.